# Android - How to create a thumbnail from a ImageView in Titanium 2.1.3?

Tags: android, imageview, titanium, appcelerator

I'm working on Titanium SDK 2.1.3 and I was wondering what are my options to create a thumbnail from a ImageView. In iOS the blob object has a imageAsThumbnail method which is not support by Android.

What options do I have to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the modules provided by appcelerator. Look in the example files for instructions

https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/imagefactory/mobile

Comment: I got an error message saying : `Requested module not found: ti.imagefactory`. I added the line `var ImageFactory = require('ti.imagefactory');` as shown on the link you provided, am I missing something else?

Comment: yes, did you follow the instructions for adding the module to your project? Did you check the tiapp.xml to see if it is there?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I thought it was integrated into the SDK. Thanks it worked apparently.

Comment: the module is moved to another repository: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.imagefactory or can be installed with gitt.io: http://gitt.io/component/ti.imagefactory